# CallContext LogicalGet(Set)Data does not work on the NUnit framework with async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, async-await

According to [this awesome blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html), we can safely set/get data from CallContext's LogicalContext even with async/await (as long as .NET 4.5 and Immutable Data is used).

Let's look at the following simple program:

```
...
CallContext.LogicalSetData("id", "123");
var id1 = CallContext.LogicalGetData("id");
await Task.Delay(100);
var id2 = CallContext.LogicalGetData("id");
...
```

When this runs in a standard console program, everything works fine - Both id1 and id2 contains the value, "123".

However, if this runs in a NUnit method, id2 contains NULL while id1 has the value '123".

Is there any reason why it does not work in the NUnit framework?

Comment: See what happens when you run it with /domain:none

Comment: How exactly do you run the unit test? From Visual Studio? Using ReSharper? Something else?

Comment: Please provide your NUnit version and how do you run your unit test (Visual Studio/NUnit GUI/ReSharper).

Comment: I'm using the latest version of NUnit (2.6.3), and it is run by ResSharper (via Visual Studio)

Comment: @Hans: where do i need to specify "/domain:none"?

Comment: I was able to duplicate this, and I verified that `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null` and `TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default`. I recommend raising the issue with the NUnit team.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of a test containing a code snippet similar to what you posted is correct when run under NUnit's native runners (GUI and Console), i.e. both *id1* and *id2* have value "123" and you can reproduce it by running the test below and checking the output in the GUI and Console.

```
[Test]
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    CallContext.LogicalSetData("id", "123");
    var id1 = CallContext.LogicalGetData("id");
    Console.WriteLine("ID1: " + id1);
    await Task.Delay(100);
    var id2 = CallContext.LogicalGetData("id");
    Console.WriteLine("ID2: " + id2);
}
```

As you are using R# to run your tests that is the most likely reason for this mis-behavior.

It's worth noting that the behavior is correct under GUI and Console even if the test is *async void*.

Comment: Thanks Simone. Yes it is working on NUnit GUI. Hm... So is it a problem of ReSharper?

Comment: To the best of my understanding yes, it's worth checking with them though.